# Deduce informations with pairs using programmation

Tags: r, database, loops, dataframe

I would like to analyze data.

My Database is composed of 1408 (704 for type 1 and 704 for type 2) observations and 49 variables. Here is part of my database.

The point is that I want to analyze gender of type 1(sellers) who overcharged.

```
 Data
 Subject ID  Gender   Period   Matching group   Group    Type  Overcharging
   654        1           1            73         1        1      NA
   654        1           2            73         1        1      NA
   654        1           3            73         1        1      NA
   654        1           4            73         1        1      NA 
   708        0           1            73         1        2       1
   708        0           2            73         1        2       0
   708        0           3            73         1        2       0
   708        0           4            73         1        2       1
   435        1           1            73         2        1      NA
   435        1           2            73         2        1      NA
   435        1           3            73         2        1      NA
   435        1           4            73         2        1      NA    
   546        0           1            73         2        2       0
   546        0           2            73         2        2       0
   546        0           3            73         2        2       1
   546        0           4            73         2        2       0
```

For example, if you take a look at matching group =73, there are 2 groups (1 and 2).And in each group, there are two types (1 and 2). For each type 1 (seller) we do not have information about what he did (overcharge or not). But we have informations about buyers (type 2) who were overcharged or not.

If I can identify the buyer who were over-treated, then, this means that the seller this buyer is interacting has over-treated the buyer. So all I need to look at is the gender of the seller in the same group as the buyer.

In matching group 73 we know for instance that at period 1 subject 708 was overcharged (the one in group 1). As I know that this men belongs to group 1 and matching group 73, I am able to identify the seller who has overcharged him : subject 654 with gender =1.

In group 2 (matching group 73), we know that at period 3, agent 546 was overcharged. As I know that this men belongs to group 1 and matching group 73, I am able to identify the seller who has overcharged him : subject 435 with gender =1.
....
I would do this for all the observations I have.

However I really don't know how to proceed to code and make this condition on R.

This is what I tried to do, but doesn't fit my needs !

```
  for (matchinggroup[type==1]==matchinggroup[type==2] & 
group[type==1]==group[type==2] & period[type==1]==period[type==2])
  {
    if ((overtreatment==1), na.rm=TRUE)
sum(gender==1[type==1], na.rm=TRUE)
  }
```

The expected output I would like to have is :

```
    sum(overcharging==1[gender==1&type==1])
    >3
    sum(overcharging==1[gender==0&type==1])
    >0
    sum(overcharging==0[gender==1&type==1])
    >5
    sum(overcharging==0[gender==0&type==1])
    >0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your desired output is, but consider this:

```
Data <- read.table(header = T, 
                   text = "Subject_ID  Gender   Period   Matching_group   Group    Type  Overcharging
654        1           1            73         1        1      NA
654        1           2            73         1        1      NA
654        1           3            73         1        1      NA
654        1           4            73         1        1      NA 
708        0           1            73         1        2       1
708        0           2            73         1        2       0
708        0           3            73         1        2       0
708        0           4            73         1        2       1
435        1           1            73         2        1      NA
435        1           2            73         2        1      NA
435        1           3            73         2        1      NA
435        1           4            73         2        1      NA    
546        0           1            73         2        2       0
546        0           2            73         2        2       0
546        0           3            73         2        2       1
546        0           4            73         2        2       0
")

dat1 <- subset(Data, Overcharging==1)
```

This will find all the Overcharging sellers. And then you could find each matching buyer using this loop:

```
out <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:nrow(dat1)){
  dat2 <- dat1[i,]
  df <- Data[Data$Period==dat2$Period & Data$Matching_group==dat2$Matching_group &
     Data$Group==dat2$Group & Data$Type==1,]
  out <- rbind(out, df)
}
```

Which will give you:

```
    Subject_ID Gender Period Matching_group Group Type Overcharging
1         654      1      1             73     1    1           NA
4         654      1      4             73     1    1           NA
11        435      1      3             73     2    1           NA
```

Comment: That fits perfectly ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think "for loop" solution is not suitable in R.

I developed another solution for you with data.table by seperating sellers and buyers, and then joining them.

```
library(data.table)
Data <- data.table(read.table(header = T, 
                   text = "Subject_ID  Gender   Period   Matching_group   Group    Type  Overcharging
                   654        1           1            73         1        1      NA
                   654        1           2            73         1        1      NA
                   654        1           3            73         1        1      NA
                   654        1           4            73         1        1      NA 
                   708        0           1            73         1        2       1
                   708        0           2            73         1        2       0
                   708        0           3            73         1        2       0
                   708        0           4            73         1        2       1
                   435        1           1            73         2        1      NA
                   435        1           2            73         2        1      NA
                   435        1           3            73         2        1      NA
                   435        1           4            73         2        1      NA    
                   546        0           1            73         2        2       0
                   546        0           2            73         2        2       0
                   546        0           3            73         2        2       1
                   546        0           4            73         2        2       0
                   ")
)

Data[, SubjectType := ifelse(Type==1, "Seller", "Buyer")]
Subjects <- unique(Data[, .(Subject_ID, Gender)])
Matches <- dcast(Data, Matching_group+Group~SubjectType, value.var="Subject_ID", fun.aggregate = mean)

Buys <- Data[!is.na(Overcharging), .(Buyer = Subject_ID, BuyerGender = Gender, Period, Matching_group, Group, Overcharging)]
Buys <- merge(Buys, Matches, by=c("Buyer", "Matching_group", "Group"), all.x = T)
Buys <- merge(Buys, Subjects[, .(Seller = Subject_ID, SellerGender = Gender)], by="Seller", all.x = T)

Buys[Overcharging==0, .N, .(BuyerGender, SellerGender)]
Buys[Overcharging==1, .N, .(BuyerGender, SellerGender)]
```